# Нужно создать словарь с пронумерованными буквами

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

alph=list(ascii_lowercase)

anglphbt=dict((x,y) for x in alph for y in range(1,26))

print(anglphbt)
```

> {'a': 25, 'b': 25, 'c': 25, 'd': 25, 'e': 25, 'f': 25, 'g': 25, 'h': 25, 'i': 25, 'j': 25, 'k': 25, 'l': 25, 'm': 25, 'n': 25, 'o': 25, 'p': 25, 'q': 25, 'r': 25, 's': 25, 't': 25, 'u': 25, 'v': 25, 'w': 25, 'x': 25, 'y': 25, 'z': 25}

Почему не работает конструктор второй переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что выражение `dict((x,y) for x in alph for y in range(1,26))` эквивалентно

```
anglphbt = dict()
for x in alph:
    for y in range(1, 26):
        anglphbt[x] = y
```

То есть каждому ключу 25 раз присваиваются разные значения, а остаётся последнее, естественно.

Да и вообще в коде много лишнего

```
anglphbt = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
```